# MySQL - INSERT IGNORE increments the auto_increment primary key

Tags: python, mysql, cpanel

Whenever an `INSERT IGNORE` statement encounters a duplicate entry the Auto Increment primary key is incremented.

I am on cpanel based shared hosting so how do i try using `innodb_autoinc_lock_mode=0`on MySQL?

I am using python-mysql library to insert values into the database..here is the snipper:

`cursor.execute ("""INSERT IGNORE INTO database (title, introduction) VALUES (%s, %s)""", (title, pure_introduction))`

Comment: Can you post a code snipet that demonstrates the problem you describe? It doesn't have to be your actual code, just keep it [minimal](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: code snippet added to the question :)

Answer (score 0):

You can not. The autoinc_lock_mode is a global variable and you can not set it as a normal user (unless if you are admin of the server, then you can set it in mysql config file)

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_autoinc_lock_mode

What you can do is manually checking the duplicates before inserting if you really want consequtice autoincrement values.